# Rename sorting options on theme Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, sorting, rename, elementor

How can I change the filter options, I have searched from the file manager but I can't find the correct .php file.

The theme I am using belongs to MasterStudy.

*I want to change these two options to Spanish

[image]

You can't change it from the Wordpress customization or Elementor.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you just go with the direct edit method in the file. That is, find the file, the appropriate line, and edit the item. However, when you can't find it, the best way in my opinion is to download the String Locator plugin, which searches for where a given string is located, in what file and line. In addition, this plugin allows direct editing in the file when it finds this element.

I hope it helps. :)